# strcpy in a struct gives SIGABRT

Tags: c, struct, pass-by-reference, strcpy, sigabrt

I'm currently working on an FTP client written in C, and it's working pretty good. I was successful in writing a function that connects to an FTP server and logs in with a username and password, but I'm having a problem returning errors. I have setup a `struct FTPError {};` with 3 fields:

1. `int` An error code
2. `int` An FTP error domain (specific to my function)
3. `char[256]` A user readable description

The caller of the function passes a structure by reference to the function and I fill it with the data. But I'm struggling with filling the user readable string (`char[256]`). I fill the string with `strcpy`, but when I call it, my program signals a SIGABRT. I present you a simplified piece of my code:

```
struct FTPError {
    int status;
    int domain;
    char message[FTP_ERROR_MAX];
};

typedef int FTPConnection;

FTPConnection FTPConnect(const char *hostname, const char *username, const char *password, struct FTPError *errn) {

    int socket = /* socket file descriptor */

    // Success
    if(success == 1) {
        if(errn) {
            // when I comment out the line below, no signal is sent
            strcpy(errn->message, "User successfully loged in");
            errn->status = 230;
            errn->domain = kServerReplyDomain;
        }
    }

    // return the file descriptor
    return sockfd;
}
```

PS:
This is what Xcode gives me in the error console:

```
Program loaded.
run
[Switching to process 2566]
Running…
SOCK: 3
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
kill
quit

0x00007fff824c03cc  <+0000>  mov    $0x2000025,%eax
0x00007fff824c03d1  <+0005>  mov    %rcx,%r10
0x00007fff824c03d4  <+0008>  syscall 
0x00007fff824c03d6  <+0010>  jae    0x7fff824c03dd <__kill+17> --> (points this line) 
0x00007fff824c03d8  <+0012>  jmpq   0x7fff82560a8c <cerror>
0x00007fff824c03dd  <+0017>  retq 

3 __kill
2 __abort
1 __stack_chk_fail
0 main
```

PPS: I was asked to show the code that calls the function:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    struct FTPError reply;
    FTPConnection socket;

    socket = FTPConnect("ftp.belnet.be", "anonymous", "pwd", &reply);

    printf("SOCK: %d\n", socket);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post the code that calls FTPConnect, including the code that creates the struct FTPError you pass into FTPConnect

Comment: I updated my question, but "bstpierre", where do I have to accept answers?

Comment: go back to some of your earlier questions and choose the best answer to the question and click the green checkmark next to that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably the `errn` pointer that is given to the function is not initialized properly, or otherwise invalid. Otherwise also `FTP_ERROR_MAX` could be a too small number, so that the `strcpy()` produces a buffer overflow.

Comment: Sorry, stupid question, FTP_ERROR_MAX was indeed wrong, I defined it, but didn't give it a value :$

Comment: Its default value was then 1, which is too short to hold any non-empty C string. This one time when the fact that `#define foo` has a well-defined meaning hurts you. If the meaning had been some other kind of defined and "true" value, then the `struct FTPError` declaration would not have compiled. This is also a good use for a compile time assertion in the vicinity of your `FTPConnect` implementation that validates that the member is too large enough for the longest error message you know of.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're passing a memory allocated structure and not a non-allocated pointer?
The call should be like:

```
FTPError myError;
FTPConnect(host, user, password, &myError);
```

otherwise if you prefer working with a pointer:

```
FTPError* myError = (FTPError*) malloc(sizeof(FTPError));
FTPConnect(host, user, password, myError);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what it says, I'd guess that you corrupted your stack with some of the other code and that it just shows up here at that place.

Anyhow, to be sure you should always initialize your `errn` structure with something like

```
 struct FTPError reply = { .status = 0 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a save strcpy variation instead:

```
strncpy(errn->message, "any string with unknown length", FTP_ERROR_MAX-1 );
errn->message[ FTP_ERROR_MAX-1 ] = 0;
```